# “Faire” being used to mean “avoir l’air”?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, verbes, langage-informel

When can “faire” be used to mean “avoir l’air” and when would you choose to use one or the other?

I recently saw both *”Ça fait un peu ringard”* and *”Ça fait classe”* and both seem to use it to mean “That looks x”.

So why was “faire” used instead of “avoir l’air”? Is it more of an informal thing?

Answer (score 10):

Rather than *avoir l'air*, in your examples, the verb *faire* means *donner un air*, *donner une apparence*, as the subject is not the thing that has the appearance, but is what *gives* this appearance.

This the definition nr. 19 given [here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire) in the Wiktionary.

Ex:

> J'aime bien porter un smoking, ça fait classe (porter le smoking donne un air classe).
>
> Ne porte pas de chaussettes avec des sandales, ça fait ringard (porter des chaussettes avec des sandales donne un air ringard).
>
> Arrête de parler en verlan, ça fait racaille (parler en verlan donne un air racaille).

Answer (score 5):

When followed by an adjective or a noun (with no article) *faire* can indeed be synonym of *avoir l'air*/*paraître*.

This particular meaning derives from one of the numerous meanings of *faire*. The *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* lists six semantic groups for the meaning of *faire*:

I. *Réaliser (qqch. ou qqn), agir de manière à faire exister.  (construire, fabriquer une maison* - to build a house)
II. *Effectuer. (une opération, un travail* - to perform)
**III. *Déterminer dans sa manière d'être*. (to make)**
IV. *Être la cause de*. (*faire tomber* - to drop, *faire avancer* - to move forward)
 V. *Exprimer les contions de l'atmosphère. (Il fait beau* - the weather's fine)
VI. *Emploi comme substitut d'un autre verbe* (this use is outdated). (*Je ne parle pas comme il le fait* (nowadays it's more usual to repeat the verb in such a sentence: *je ne parle pas comme il parle* - I don't speak as he does)

N° III, the meaning we are interested in here, appeared at the end of the 10th century. In the *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* we can follow the semantic evolution thus:

1. *Arranger, mettre dans un état convenable. (Faire son lit)*
   ↓
2. *Former, instruire. (Cette école fait de bons traducteurs)*
   ↓
3. *Donner une qualité. (Il a été fait général)*
   ↓
4. *Changer, transformer. (Ils en ont fait un bon petit soldat)*
   ↓
5. *Représenter, agir comme*. (*Isabelle Adajni a fait Marguerite Gautier dans « La dame aux camélias »*, *faire l'idiot*)
   ↓
6. *Avoir l'air de, donner l'impression*.

Although *faire* can only be synonym of *avoir l'air* if followed by an adjective or a noun (without an article), we would not always use *faire* in all cases where it is followed by an adjective or a noun. For example I would never use it to say :

> *Ce gâteau a l'air cuit.* (that cake looks cooked).
>   *Elle a l'air prête*. (It looks as if she's ready).

The only reason for that I can find so far is that we will not use *faire* if a transformation is involved, but only when referring to the innate quality of something or someone. It's only an assumption though, because I can find no better explanation at the moment.

Personally I would not always interchange *faire* and *avoir l'air* even when possible. There's a feeling, maybe not of informality but of triteness about *faire*, and I would tend to avoid using it whenever I can.

Comment: Il semble que LBU14 l’identifie comme appartenant à la langue familière (§ 249 f) et donne des exemples où l'adjectif s'accorde (« La maison faisait grande [...] », Aragon) ou non (« Elle ne fait pas vieux ! Quel âge a-t-elle », Troyat).